# Appengine JS setting max_concurrent_request turns threadsafe to False

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm deploying my app to Appengine Standard JS. When I set the `max_concurrent_request` value, `threadsafe` becomes false on the console. Please clarify.

Attached is a screenshot for the same.

[image: Screenshot of the console]

Answer (score 2):

Node.JS is built to be thread safe by default, therefore the threadsafe element does not work for GAE applications serving in Node.JS, according to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled).

However, Threadsafe should not be changed to False when setting `max_concurrent_requests`. We are currently working on this issue with the App Engine team and will let you know when I have any updates regarding this matter.

**Edit:**
Just as an update, the issue is actively being handled. No ETA at the moment.